# Getting error when trying to bundle fast_stack on windows

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-4, discourse, helicontech, heliconzoo

I'm trying to understand how to fix error:

```
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DISCOU~2>gem install fast_stack
ERROR:  Error installing fast_stack:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating fast_stack-i386-mingw32.def
compiling fast_stack.c
In file included from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153:0,
                 from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from fast_stack.c:3:
c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:276:12: error: conflicting types for 'gettimeofday'
In file included from fast_stack.c:2:0:
c:\ruby200\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/sys/time.h:42:13: note: previous declaration of 'gettimeofday' was here
fast_stack.c: In function 'rb_profile_start':
fast_stack.c:9:22: error: storage size of 'timer' isn't known
fast_stack.c:11:34: error: 'suseconds_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
fast_stack.c:11:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
fast_stack.c:11:46: error: expected ';' before 'rb_num2long_inline'
fast_stack.c:13:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'setitimer' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
fast_stack.c:13:15: error: 'ITIMER_REAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
fast_stack.c:9:22: warning: unused variable 'timer' [-Wunused-variable]
fast_stack.c: In function 'rb_profile_stop':
fast_stack.c:21:22: error: storage size of 'timer' isn't known
fast_stack.c:23:15: error: 'ITIMER_REAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
fast_stack.c:21:22: warning: unused variable 'timer' [-Wunused-variable]
make: *** [fast_stack.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/DISCOU~2/GEM_HOME/gems/fast_stack-0.1.0 for inspection.
```

It happens when I write "bundle install" command for the discourse.org application installing on Helicon Zoo environment.

Comment: As the gem author said, in this github issue discussion, this gem unfortunately was not meant to run on windows.
https://github.com/SamSaffron/fast_stack/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it's not the Zoo itself, more issue with the gem. Try to install it separately, outside the environment of Zoo. Simply Ruby, in test catalog, but outside the Zoo. If that's working, contact HeliconTech directly and address as an issue, they're quite quick and good at fixing these things.

Comment: While the problem is no longer relevant for me, just for sake, I created a folder in the directory C:/ruby200 and run the command "gem install fast_stask". The result is the same. Obviously the problem in the compatibility of the gem and windows.